# Convert a string array to byte array

Tags: c#

I want to make a file which reads String array but initially I am having only byte array so first I want to convert it into string array, so how can I do so.

Comment: Use StreamReader to read strings from a file.  File.ReadAllLines() is the quick way.

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
Byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourString);
```

You may need to change this up depending on the [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) of your string - please see [`System.Text.Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding_members%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (specifically its properties) for other encodings that are supported by this type.

If you need to go the other way (and convert a `Byte[]` to a `String`) then do this (The advice on character encoding still applies here as well):

```
String yourString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(yourByteArray);
```

It sounds like your the API you are using expects a `String[]` and a call to `GetString` will provide you with just a single instance of `String`, not an array.  Perhaps something like this will work for your API call:

```
String yourString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(yourByteArray);
someType.ApiCall(new[] { yourString });
```