# C# String[] to byte[][]

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine, mono

I have a string array I need to convert to byte[][] (to connect Xcode with Unity scripts in C#).

This is the functions in Xcode:

```
void doThisC(char** matrix);
```

And in Unity in C#, this is what I have but I'm not able to make it work:

```
public static void doThis(string[] array, int size){
    char[][] grid = new char[][] { new char[size] , new char[100]}; 
    byte[][] buffer;

   for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
   {
      grid[i] = array[i].ToString().ToCharArray();
      buffer[i] = (new System.Text.UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(grid[i]);
   }
   doThisC(buffer);     
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658943/convert-a-string-array-to-byte-array

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grid` array only has two items, so the code will only work up to two strings. You don't need the `grid` array at all. Also, you don't create the array `buffer`:

```
public static void doThis(string[] array){
   byte[][] buffer = new byte[array.Length][];
   for(int i = 0 ; i < array.Length ; i++)
   {
      buffer[i] = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(array[i]);
   }
   doThisC(buffer);     
}
```

or using Linq extension methods:

```
public static void doThis(string[] array){
   byte[][] buffer = array.Select(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes).ToArray();
   doThisC(buffer);     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is just with array creation, you should first create a byte array properly:

```
byte[][] buffer = new byte[size][];
```

In your current implementation, when you call `buffer[i]` you will get an exception, but you can fix it with little change as mentioned above. Other parts of your code (depending to your encoding), seems correct.